# Can't retrieve Double from HashMap<Integer, Double>

Tags: java, android, hashmap, gson

Somehow I can't retrieve a Double from a HashMap I've made using Gson.

```
Map<Integer, Double> ratingMap = (Map<Integer, Double>) new GsonBuilder()
            .create().fromJson(json, Map.class);
Integer ifilmId = filmId;
Double rating = ratingMap.get(ifilmId);
```

In this code I've veried that the ratingMap contains {2=5.0}, but when I do `ratingMap.get(ifilmId)` (where I've verified that ifilmId is in fact 2), the variable `rating` is null. Am I missing something here?

I create the HashMap in the following way:

```
if (json.equals("")) {
        // noting ever saved
        ratingMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        ratingMap.put(filmId, rating);

} else {
        ratingMap = (Map<Integer, Integer>) new GsonBuilder().create()
                .fromJson(json, Map.class);
        ratingMap.put(Integer.valueOf(filmId), rating);
}
```

I let Gson format the Integer to a Double, and that seems to work fine but I can't retrieve it.

**The total code, including saving to Androids SharedPreferences**

```
public void saveRating(int rating, int filmId) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            LOCAL_MEM_KEY, 0);
    String json = sharedPref.getString(LOCAL_MAP_RATING_KEY, "");
    Map<Integer, Integer> ratingMap;
    if (json.equals("")) {
        // noting ever saved
        ratingMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        ratingMap.put(filmId, rating);

    } else {
        ratingMap = (Map<Integer, Integer>) new GsonBuilder().create()
                .fromJson(json, Map.class);
        ratingMap.put(Integer.valueOf(filmId), rating);
    }

    json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(ratingMap, Map.class);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(LOCAL_MAP_RATING_KEY, json);
    editor.commit();
}

/*
 * returns null if no rating found
 */
public Map<Integer, Integer> getRatingFor(int filmId) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            LOCAL_MEM_KEY, 0);
    String json = sharedPref.getString(LOCAL_MAP_RATING_KEY, "");
    if (json.equals("")) {
        return null;
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> ratingMap = (Map<Integer, Integer>) new GsonBuilder()
            .create().fromJson(json, Map.class);
    Log.d("map", ratingMap.toString());
    Integer ifilmId = filmId;
    Integer rating = ratingMap.get(ifilmId);
    if(rating == null) { //because of this we have to prevent a 0 rating
        return null;
    } else {
        Map<Integer, Integer> returnMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        returnMap.put(filmId, rating.intValue());
        return returnMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing a `map.put(2, 4.0)` and then print the `map`. See what you get.

Comment: You create a `Map<Integer, Integer>` and you try to get a `Map<Integer, Double>` ?

Comment: @AlexisC. Yes. Gson does format it correctly. When I change the retrieved Map to 'Map<Integer, Integer>' the problem persists.

Comment: and you say that the `Log.d("map", ratingMap.toString());` prints `{2=5.0}` and that `ifilmId` is 2 and you get `null`?

Comment: @AlexisC. Yes, exactly. It is extremely odd.

Comment: Well could you try to post a small program demonstrating the problem? I don't think it's related to `SharedPreferences`, so a simple Java program with the JSON you are trying to save is fine.

Comment: How do you know that `ratingMap` is a `HashMap`? Have you tried logging `ratingMap.getClass().toString()`? How do you know that the key that you see when you look at `{2=5.0}` is actually an `Integer`? Couldn't it be a `BigInteger` or something? Have you tried `for (Object object : ratingMap.keySet()) { Log.d("map", object.getClass().toString(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your not passing a null variable when saving

```
saveRating(int rating, int filmId){
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(rating));
}
```

---

```
if (json.equals("")) {
    // noting ever saved
    ratingMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();    <--- Double not Integer
    ratingMap.put(filmId, 5.0);

} else {
    ratingMap = (Map<Integer, Double>) new GsonBuilder().create()
            .fromJson(json, Map.class);           <--- double not Integer
    ratingMap.put(Integer.valueOf(filmId), 5.0);
}
```

Make sure when using Doubles to
use 5.0
not 5

Comment: I've tried using Double.valueOf(rating). But it didn't work. The retrieved keeps returning null while my logcat does indicat {2=4.0}

Answer (score -1):

```
public void saveRating(Double rating, int filmId) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(LOCAL_MEM_KEY, 0);
    String json = sharedPref.getString(LOCAL_MAP_RATING_KEY, "");
    Map<Integer, Double> ratingMap;
    if (json.equals("")) {
        // noting ever saved
        ratingMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    } else {
        ratingMap = (Map<Integer, Double>) new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, Map.class);
    }
    ratingMap.put(filmId, rating);
    ratingMap.put(3, 5.0d); // JUST FOR TEST
    json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(ratingMap, Map.class);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putString(LOCAL_MAP_RATING_KEY, json);
    editor.commit();
}

/*
 * returns null if no rating found
 */
public Map<Integer, Double> getRatingFor(int filmId) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(LOCAL_MEM_KEY, 0);
    String json = sharedPref.getString(LOCAL_MAP_RATING_KEY, "");

    if (json.equals("")) {
        return null;
    }

    Map<Integer, Double> ratingMap = (Map<Integer, Double>) new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, Map.class);
    Log.d("map", ratingMap.toString());
    Log.d("map", ratingMap.get(3) + ""); // JUST FOR TEST
    Integer ifilmId = filmId;
    Double rating = ratingMap.get(ifilmId);

    if (rating == null) { //because of this we have to prevent a 0 rating
        return null;
    } else {
        Map<Integer, Double> returnMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
        returnMap.put(filmId, rating);
        return returnMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"You mutate objects in the HashMap. To do so is prohibited"* Nope. From where did you get that?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get the answer. Where am I mutating the HashMap?

Comment: But I'm only calling .put once for one unique key. After that I am calling .put on for a different key.

Comment: @TimKranen give me a minute :)

Comment: I have tried this. The problem persists. The map to string prints: {2=5.0}, and when using a .get(filmId) where filmId = 2, the rating that is returned as a double is null.

Comment: @TimKranen try my code. I added test **put** action. That helps to you localize error.

Comment: "you add objects instead of re-write them" - No. `HashMap` is based on equality of keys, not references, so putting new `Integer` key with the same value you just overwrite it with new corresponding `Double` map value. If objects are equal in terms of Java, their hash codes by contract are also equal, so there is no way for two `Integer(2)` objects to be placed in different buckets.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou if **keys** equality hashmap check for equality **values**.